# What is this spider? Two black stripes

Tags: species-identification

[image]

When I opened my front door, there were five of this type of spider sitting on the door. I can't quite find anything online matching the two black stripes on it's back.

I vacummed them up before I realized I should identify them, so the above picture is the only one I have available. (I like spiders, but there were too many.) I'd feel more comfortable if someone could identify the spider and determine it's threat level.

Details:

- Inch or so longer
- Brown
- North East Wisconsin
- Wooded Area with little to no grass
- Mile away from lake Michigan
- Jumpers
- Party of about 5
- Door was in direct sunlight

Comment: It's hard to see from where the picture is a bit blurry, but does the spider look anything like [this](http://bugguide.net/images/cache/BLS/ZOL/BLSZOLKZWL8R3ZMRJZER0HPRLH2RCLPRYZYLULLZOLKZ0HKZZH6RVL8RHHQZHH2R0HMZSH6ROL5RHH0RULQRYZHZWL.jpg) or [this](http://itp.lucidcentral.org/id/table-grape/tgspid/html/images/sp_hololena_nedra/TGSpID-Holol_ned_male_habitus_op.jpg)? I'm assuming the legs are different..

Comment: It's like, a mix between a nursery web spider and a wolf spider..ahhh.

Comment: It musb be a Lycosa erythrognatha

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the stripes, it's most likely a [wolf spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_spider).

[image]

If they didn't have a web I would say they're almost certainly wolf spiders, since they don't build webs. Like most spiders in North America, they are harmless to humans.

Comment: The stripes in your specimen are drastically different from the OP's spider. This is not a good answer. Please consider updating with more evidence.

Comment: The family of Lycosidae (wolf spiders) is correct, but it is hard to justify with evidence aside from the general shape/proportions and colour and the geography of the observation. The most telling attribute to ID wolf spiders is the eye arrangement but they can't be seen in the quality of the pic provided in the question.

Comment: The spider in the original post is probably genus Gladicosa.

Answer (score 0):

I think the spider you have found must be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tegenaria_domestica

In europe this is called the Domestic house spider,It can bite humans and pets the bite is painless.

This spider is common in Europe-USA-Canada.

Comment: No, the pictured specimen is not T.domestica or any funnel weaver. It does not have the abdominal markings or leg annulations or spinnerets. The spider in question is most likely a wolf spider.

Comment: @JimN thank you for the feedback,if it is a wolf spider you should upvote the other answer it is how our site works ,good answers should be upvoted and bad answers like mine should not.you might consider making an answer to the question yourself.